# Liferay 6.1 dynamic data list in velocity

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity, dynamic-data-list

I build some custom views for DDL. For text type fields i'd iterate through records and display just like below:

```
$record.getField("field_name").getValue()
```

This won't work for the date field. I presume I should use getRenderedValue(themeDisplay) method instead of getValue()

I can access themeDisplay in velocity markup through request.get("theme-display"),
however if i set it as variable and pass as argument to getRenderedValue method I get no result

Is this the right way to do it? Whats the best practice to obtain themeDisplay in velocity markup?

Answer (score 3):

I think it should work when you iterate through the records. I presume, before iterating you have done

```
$serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService"))
#set ($recordSetId = $getterUtil.getLong($reserved_record_set_id.data))
#set ($records = ${ddlRecordsUtil.getRecords($recordSetId)})
```

1st Check: Can you print records? If No, Can you please check that you have added this property in your portal-ext.properties file?

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

By default it will be

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=serviceLocator
```

you need to remove serviceLocator and then try?

HTH